# How to display template when scope change [Angular directive]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my directive:

```
function ajaxMessageData()
{
    var ajaxMessage = {
        link: link,
        restrict: "EA",
        template: "success",
        scope: {
            success: '='
        }
    };

    return ajaxMessage;

    function link(scope, elm, attrs)
    {

            console.log(scope.success);
            scope.$watch(attrs.success, function (newValue) {
                console.log("Changed to " + newValue);
            });

    }
}
```

and in html:

```
<ajax-message success="vm.message"></ajax-message>
```

Problem is with scope inside directive I get initial message from `vm.message` (it is my controller var) but when my `vm.message` change it not detectd in directive... Also I would like to template show only if I get success message from `vm.success`. Anyone know how to accomplish this?
Thanks

Comment: Try `scope.$apply()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You're passing the wrong argument to the `$watch`. It should be an expression -- not the value of the `attrs` object.
2. You can use the `ng-if` directive to control visibility.
3. Not sure if this is intended, but the success template maybe needs a curly binding: `"{{ success }}"`

**Example:**

```
myApp.directive('ajaxMessage', function() {

  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
      success: '='
    },

    // Use anything you like in the template -- note the ng-if will only
    // render the element when the success property has a value
    // Also note the {{ binding }}

    template: "<div ng-if=\"success\" class=\"alert alert-info\">{{ success }}</div>",

    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {

      // Watching $scope.success (not the $attrs.success)

      $scope.$watch('success', function(value) {
        console.log('Success is now:', value);  
      });
    }
  };

});
```

... or see this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/DadKmIaHbJvhcTudCQ3i?p=preview) in action.